# How to add Buttons after created a Jquery Dialog UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a jquery dialog and needs to add buttons to it.

I'm using the following code which works fine in IE but not in Mozilla.

Can any one figure out what is the issue here?

```
function dialog_box(dynDiv, rootTemplate) {
    var dialog_buttons = rootTemplate.buttons;
    var dialog = $("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
        hide: "explode",
        title: rootTemplate.etype,
        buttons:'',
        text: rootTemplate.text,
        resizable: true,
        minWidth: 200,
        minHeight: 150,
        close: function () {
            $(dialog).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });


    var buttonSet = $("#" + dynDiv.id).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonset');
    $.each(dialog_buttons, function (index, props) {
        var newButton = $('<button></button>', {
            id: "btn" + dynDiv.id + props.id,
            text: props.text
        });
        newButton.button().unbind().on("click", props.handler);

        $(buttonSet).append(newButton);      
    });


}
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AvF8V/12/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
// Retrieve buttons hash
var buttons = dialog.dialog("option", "buttons"); 
// Extend the hash (so you're able to keep the old buttons)
$.extend(buttons, { props.text: props.handler } );
// Set it again
dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
```

Comment: I have modified the sample code. Despite the syntax error, does it work?

Comment: To expand on @KT, you can also add additional buttons like `$.extend({}, {props.text: props.handler}, buttons);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create buttons as options, using buttons option, when creating dialog:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
    buttons: [ { 
        text: "Ok", 
        click: function() { 
            $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
        } 
    } ] 
});
```

Comment: I cant specify values as you provided. I need to get values from an input variable to create the button.

Comment: you can set the option after the dialog is created also calling $(".selector").dialog("option", "buttons", ...)

Answer (score 0):

I made small changes in the code posted and it works fine. modified part highlighted.

```
function dialog_box(dynDiv, rootTemplate) {
        var dialog_buttons = rootTemplate.buttons;
        var dialog = $("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
            hide: "explode",
            title: rootTemplate.etype,
            **buttons:[{}],**
            text: rootTemplate.text,
            resizable: true,
            minWidth: 200,
            minHeight: 150,
            close: function () {
                $(dialog).dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
        });


        var buttonSet = $("#" + dynDiv.id).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonset');
        **$(buttonSet).empty();**
        $.each(dialog_buttons, function (index, props) {
            var newButton = $('<button></button>', {
                id: "btn" + dynDiv.id + props.id,
                text: props.text
            });
            newButton.button().unbind().on("click", props.handler);

            $(buttonSet).append(newButton);      
        });


    }
```

So an empty button set has been added while creating the JqueryUI dialog.
After cleared the button set I had added the buttons to it.

Comment: Did you try @KT utilization of `$.extend`?  There is an alternative if you need the new buttons before the prescribed initialization ones: `$.extend({}, {props.text: props.handler}, buttons);`