# Add Additional Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a scenario where i have a standard set of buttons to be available within the jQuery Dialog box but based on other conditions, I need to add additional buttons.

Good news is that I wont need to Add/Remove buttons, just Add.  These buttons will effectively trigger a PostBack, forcing a refresh of the page content.

```
$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons',
    {   // @buttons
        "Add": function (evt) {
            $(btnAdd).click();

            // Close
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function (evt) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
);

$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons',
    {   // @buttons
        "Search": function (evt) {
            $(btnSubmit).click();

            // Close
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function (evt) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
);
```

### Question

How do I have a common Dialog Init and then come back later and add the unique set of buttons for the scenarios?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/button/

Comment: yeah i have tried `options`

Comment: @mplungjan I want to setup a dialog with a set of buttons and then later add more buttons

Comment: Please create a [mcve] perhaps with a drawing of what you want

Comment: @mplungjan MCVE is present, just have to read

Comment: You have 1500 rep and you call an incomplete snippet of code "Complete" ? Please add the HTML and the script. Then we can inspect the code and insert buttons depending on rendered HTML. Or don't. I am just trying to help

Comment: It for example looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174939/how-to-add-buttons-after-created-a-jquery-dialog-ui

Comment: @mplungjan read up on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll  The code is complete as far as it pertains to the question...two simple code snippets with similar setups, except the buttons.  Anything else is just Mud in the Water....

Comment: Then all is well. Have a great xmas. I am an internet troll now.

Comment: More trolling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021107/can-i-dynamically-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-ui-dialog-box

Comment: And more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031673/add-button-to-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: @mplungjan found my solution from `6021107`, not exactly what I needed but posting the solution for others to consume in a different context from those other questions

Comment: But I am still just a troll :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19175417/659246

```
// Setup standard settings for Dialog
InitDialog(divSearch, 315
    , { // @buttons
        "Cancel": function (evt) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
    , function (evt) {  // @open
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    });

// In a Function...Far, Far, Away from the Document.Ready
var btns = $(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons');
$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons'
    , $.extend({}, {
        "Search": function (evt) {
            $(btnSubmit).click();

            // Close
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, btns)
);
```

I used `$.extend` to get my desired result.

#### Explanation

capture the existing Buttons:

```
var btns = $(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons');
```

Pending on your need, I need to add a button in front of the standard set:

```
$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons'
    , $.extend({}, {
        "Search": function (evt) {
            $(btnSubmit).click();

            // Close
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, btns)
);
```

If you don't care on the order, then simply do this:

```
$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons'
    , $.extend(btns, {
        "Search": function (evt) {
            $(btnSubmit).click();

            // Close
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    })
);
```

If you need to Add, Subtract, or Change the button(s) object, then you can do it through the `btns` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed under the API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", 
  [
    {
      text: "Ok",
      icon: "ui-icon-heart",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }

      // Uncommenting the following line would hide the text,
      // resulting in the label being used as a tooltip
      //showText: false
    }
  ]
);
```

Your example was missing the Array. Applied to your example, this would be:

```
$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons', [
  {
    text: "Add",
    click: function () {
      $(btnAdd).click();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  },
    text: "Cancel",
    click:function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
]);

$(divSearch).dialog('option', 'buttons', [
  {
    text: "Search",
    click: function () {
      $(btnSubmit).click();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  },
  {
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
]);
```

Hope that helps. You could also apply all the buttons and `.show()` or `.hide()` the ones you need.

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Add",
      id: "ui-btn-add",
      class: "add",
      click: function() {
        $(btnAdd).click();
        $("#ui-btn-add, #ui-btn-search").hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Search",
      id: "ui-btn-search",
      class: "search",
      click: function() {
        $(btnSubmit).click();
        $("#ui-btn-add, #ui-btn-search").hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $("#ui-btn-add, #ui-btn-search").hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
  $("#ui-btn-add, #ui-btn-search").hide();
  $("button[id*='opener']").click(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).hasClass("add")) {
      $("#ui-btn-add").show();
    } else {
      $("#ui-btn-search").show();
    }
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dow48098/

Comment: This is partially correct...your example/answer assumes to have all the buttons programmed into the dialog during Init and then show/hide the appropriate button based on need.  In my case, I prefer only loading what is needed at the time of need...nothing wrong with yours, just not my pattern or practice.

Comment: @GoldBishop I do understand and the example above would work better for you. Instead of Hiding buttons, you would Remove them and add them back in much the same method you proposed.

Comment: Its all about context and design...yours is not wrong, it is correct pending the organizational design pattern.  Mine is more of a stripped down minimal approach.